# ViewPager along with FragmentList in Fragment Activity

Tags: android

This is my 1st question so i will try to b as precise as possible. I am trying the create an application using Fragment Activity, Fragment List and View Pager. When the activity loads by default the fragment list should be shown to the left and view pager is shown to the right (the detail view). When i click one of the fragment list buttons i want to load a webview in the detail view (right side).

I have implemented the Fragment Activity with Fragment List. Now how to add View Pager to this so that it shows up when the application loads up ..

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements McDonaldsListener {

  @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

McDonaldsFragment countries
  =(McDonaldsFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.countries);

countries.setCountryListener(this);

Fragment f=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);


  countries.enablePersistentSelection();

  }

 @Override
  public void onCountrySelected(McDonalds c) {
String url=getString(c.url);


  ((DetailsFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.details))
                        .loadUrl(url);                            


  }
 }
```

There are other supporting classes which if there is need i will post it.

Hope some one can suggest me some solutions.

Edit: 
This is what i tried to implement but dosent work....Gives Instantiation Exception :(

```
public class ViewPagerExample extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity        implements McDonaldsListener {
private MyAdapter mAdapter;
private ViewPager mPager;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    McDonaldsFragment mc
    =(McDonaldsFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
                          .findFragmentById(R.id.countries);

  mc.setCountryListener(this);

  Fragment f=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details);

    mc.enablePersistentSelection();
}

public void onCountrySelected(McDonalds c) {
  String url=getString(c.url);


    ((DetailsFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
                          .findFragmentById(R.id.details))
                          .loadUrl(url);                            


}

public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new DetailFragment();
        case 1:
            return new ImageFragment(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        case 2:
            return new ImageFragment(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        default:
            return null;
        }
    }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets try this peter kuterna view pager 
http://blog.peterkuterna.net/2011/09/viewpager-meets-swipey-tabs.html

Comment: Thanx for the reply ..... well that gives me the viewpager ....but how do i integrate it with my current code?